# Why use a jQuery class as .on click event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onclick, click

I was debugging and found that this piece of code, which was written by another dev, was breaking the site that I'm working on.

```
jQuery(document).on('click.tab.tab-link', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

This code was stopping users from clicking on a form submit. The only thing that I can think is that the 'click.tab.tab-link' event handler seen below was meant to isolate the click event to elements that have the .tab-link class, but this syntax is foreign to me. Why would someone have written this jQuery? Is including classes in event handlers a thing? or is it just bad code?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/

Comment: It's a namespaced event. Useful to identify events that you raised yourself, eg. `$('#element').trigger('click.foo');` I can then remove all the `.foo` namespaced events (when my plugin is destroyed for example) without affecting any of the other, valid, event handlers the user may have added: `$('#element').off('.foo');`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan this should really be an answer

Comment: @mmichael I'm sure it's a duplicate already, I just can't find one :)

Comment: Thank you @RoryMcCrossan, 
A namespaced event makes sense. In asking this question, I was more curious about making sure there's no way that the .tab-link class gets selected (and thus isolates the event) through this syntax.

Comment: Glad to help, and no, there's no way that this logic will interfere with any classes in the DOM - although admittedly there may be confusion if the names are not dissimilar.